# Terminal block kenmore dryer all wires connect. Have one lose bare wire where does it go

Tags: electrical, wiring

Kenmore dryer terminal block replacement now I connect the two hots and n but I have a naked wire from the cord going to dryer or terminal block where does it go or do I even need it

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is a green screw to the frame of the dryer for that wire called the equipment ground.

Answer (score 1):

The bare wire is important. It does not go to one of the 3 terminal block screws.  It goes to the ground/chassis of the machine.

However, there's another important factor.  On many dryers, there is a strap/wire/etc. from the neutral screw to the ground/chassis of the dryer. This must be removed!